# CVS equivalent of "bzr info"

Tags: cvs, bazaar

I want to know the repository URL of a CVS branch. I know "bzr info" can list it, but haven't found its CVS equivalent after searching for a while. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Can you give an example of `bzr info` for which you are trying to get the equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CVS/Root` file shows the location of the CVS repository.

```
burhan@orion:/dev/shm/cvstest/test$ cat CVS/Root
:ext:burhan@cvs:/vol/cvsroot
```

The `CVS/Repository` files shows you the location of the current directory under the CVS repository.

```
burhan@orion:/dev/shm/cvstest/test$ cat CVS/Repository 
cvstest/test
```

I don't know exactly what information from `bzr info` you are after but a combination of the above should help.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used CVS, but I think it was in the `CVS/Repository` file of your working directory. If not that specific file, one of the files in that directory.